# Issue with Object oriented concepts in php

Tags: php

I created a file by name classperson.php where I declared all the variables .

```
<?php
class person1
{
    var $location;
    var $effective;
    var $training;
    var $treated;
    var $effort;
    var $information;
    var $recognition;
    var $valued;
    var $supervisor;
    var $informed;
    var $job;
    var $treats;
    var $satisfy;
    var $workgroup;
    var $utc;
    var $skills;

    function set_location($new_location)
    {
        $this->location=$new_location;
    }
    function get_location()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }


    function set_effective($new_effective)
    {
        $this->effective=$new_effective;
    }
    function get_effective()
    {
        return $this->effective;
    }



    function set_training($new_training)
    {
            $this->training=$new_training;
    }
    function get_training()
    {
            return $this->training;
    }



    function set_treated($new_treated)
    {
        $this->treated=$new_treated;
    }
    function get_treated()
    {
        return $this->treated;
    }




    function set_effort($new_effort)
    {
        $this->effort=$new_effort;
    }
    function get_effort()
    {
        return $this->effort;
    }



    function set_information($new_information)
    {
        $this->information=$new_information;
    }
    function get_information()
    {
            return $this->information;
    }



    function set_recognition($new_recognition)
    {
        $this->recognition=$new_recognition;
    }
    function get_recognition()
    {
        return $this->recognition;
    }



    function set_valued($new_valued)
    {
        $this->valued=$new_valued;
    }
    function get_valued()
    {
            return $this->valued;
    }



    function set_supervisor($new_supervisor)
    {
        $this->supervisor=$new_supervisor;
    }
    function get_supervisor()
    {
        return $this->supervisor;
    }



    function set_informed($new_informed)
    {
        $this->informed=$new_informed;
    }
    function get_informed()
    {
        return $this->informed;
    }



    function set_job($new_job)
    {
        $this->job=$new_job;
    }
    function get_job()
    {
            return $this->job;
    }



    function set_treats($new_treats)
    {
        $this->treats=$new_treats;
    }
    function get_treats()
    {
        return $this->treats;
    }



    function set_satisfy($new_satisfy)
    {
        $this->satisfy=$new_satisfy;
    }
    function get_satisfy()
    {
            return $this->satisfy;
    }



    function set_workgroup($new_workgroup)
    {
        $this->workgroup=$new_workgroup;
    }
    function get_workgroup()
    {
            return $this->workgroup;
    }



    function set_utc($new_utc)
    {
        $this->utc=$new_utc;
    }
    function get_utc()
    {
        return $this->utc;
    }



    function set_skills($new_skills)
    {
        $this->skills=$new_skills;
    }
    function get_skills()
    {
        return $this->skills;
    }
}
?>
```

Later I have Included this file in the oopossurvey.php . This is a form which has 5 pages

Take a look into the code

```
<?php
session_start();
$session=session_id();
$_SESSION['session']=$session;
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">
Where do you work?<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="location" value="USA" <?php if($_SESSION['location'] == 'USA') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>In the United states<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="location" value="India" <?php if($_SESSION['location'] == 'India') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/>Outside of the United states<br/>

<input name="Operation1" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
<input name="Operation2" type="submit" value="next" />

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['session']==$session)
{
$location=$_SESSION['location'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
}
?>

<html>

<body>

<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">

In my work group, we are actively involved in making our work processes more effective and efficient (simpler, faster, etc.) using ACE.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effective" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

I have received the training I need to understand and implement ACE in my work group.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="training" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

All employees at the company are treated fairly regardless of differences.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treated" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

Sufficient effort is made to get the opinions and thoughts of the people who work here.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="effort" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

<input name="Operation3" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
<input name="Operation4" type="submit" value="next" />
<input name="Operation5" type="submit" value="back" />

</form>

</body>

</html>


 <?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['session']==$session)
{

    $effective=$_SESSION['effective'];

    $training=$_SESSION['training'];

    $treated=$_SESSION['treated'];

    $effort=$_SESSION['effort'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['effective']=$_POST['effective'];
    $_SESSION['training']=$_POST['training'];
    $_SESSION['treated']=$_POST['treated'];
    $_SESSION['effort']=$_POST['effort'];
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">

How satisfied are you with the information you receive from management on what's going on in the company?<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="information" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="information" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="information" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

How satisfied are you with the recognition you receive for doing a good job?<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="recognition" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="recognition" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="recognition" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

I feel valued as an employee of the company.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="valued" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="valued" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="valued" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

My immediate supervisor does a good job of coaching/guiding me.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="supervisor" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="supervisor" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="supervisor" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

<input name="Operation6" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
<input name="Operation7" type="submit" value="next" />
<input name="Operation8" type="submit" value="back" />

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();


if($_SESSION['session']==$session)
{

$information=$_SESSION['information'];

$recognition=$_SESSION['recognition'];

$valued=$_SESSION['valued'];

$supervisor=$_SESSION['supervisor'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['information']=$_POST['information'];
    $_SESSION['recognition']=$_POST['recognition'];
    $_SESSION['valued']=$_POST['valued'];
    $_SESSION['supervisor']=$_POST['supervisor'];
}
?>
<html>

<body>

<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">

I feel well informed about what is expected in my job.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="informed" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="informed" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="informed" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

Overall, how good a job do you feel is being done by your immediate supervisor<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="job" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="job" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="job" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

My immediate supervisor treats me with respect and dignity.<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treats" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treats" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="treats" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

How satisfied are you with your involvement in the decisions that affect your work?<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="satisfy" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="satisfy" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="satisfy" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

<input name="Operation9" type="submit" value="saveandresume" />
<input name="Operation10" type="submit" value="next" />
<input name="Operation11" type="submit" value="back" />

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

session_start();

if($_SESSION['session']==$session)
{

$informed=$_SESSION['informed'];

$job=$_SESSION['job'];

$treats=$_SESSION['treats'];

$satisfy=$_SESSION['satisfy'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['informed']=$_POST['informed'];
    $_SESSION['job']=$_POST['job'];
    $_SESSION['treats']=$_POST['treats'];
    $_SESSION['satisfy']=$_POST['satisfy'];
}
?>

<html>

<body>

<form action="oopssurvey.php" method="post">

Day-to-day decisions and activities in my work group demonstrate that quality is a top priority.
<Input type ="radio" name="workgroup" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="workgroup" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="workgroup" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

I have the opportunity to grow and develop at my company and/or elsewhere in UTC.
<Input type ="radio" name="utc" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="utc" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="utc" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

My job makes good use of my skills and abilities.
<Input type ="radio" name="skills" value="agree"/>Agree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="skills" value="Agreenordisagree"/>Neither Agree nor Disagree<br/>
<Input type ="radio" name="skills" value="disagree"/>Disagree<br/>

<input name="Operation12" type="submit" value="submit" />
<input name="Operation13" type="submit" value="back" />



</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php
session_start();
include 'classperson.php';

if($_POST['Operation1'])
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage2.php";
}

else if($_POST['Operation2'])
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
include "oopspage2.php";
}


elseif($_POST['Operation3'])

{
$_SESSION['effective'] = $effective;
$_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
$_SESSION['training'] = $training;
$_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
$_SESSION['treated'] = $treated;
$_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
$_SESSION['effort'] = $effort;
$_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage3.php";

}

elseif($_POST['Operation4'])
{
$_SESSION['effective'] = $effective;
$_SESSION['effective'] = $_POST['effective'];
$_SESSION['training'] = $training;
$_SESSION['training'] = $_POST['training'];
$_SESSION['treated'] = $treated;
$_SESSION['treated'] = $_POST['treated'];
$_SESSION['effort'] = $effort;
$_SESSION['effort'] = $_POST['effort'];
include "oopspage3.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation5'])
{
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;
$_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];
include "oopspage1.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation6'])
{
$_SESSION['information'] = $information;
$_SESSION['information'] = $_POST['information'];
$_SESSION['recognition'] = $recognition;
$_SESSION['recognition'] = $_POST['recognition'];
$_SESSION['valued'] = $valued;
$_SESSION['valued'] = $_POST['valued'];
$_SESSION['supervisor'] = $supervisor;
$_SESSION['supervisor'] = $_POST['supervisor'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage4.php";

}

elseif($_POST['Operation7'] )
{
$_SESSION['information'] = $information;
$_SESSION['information'] = $_POST['information'];
$_SESSION['recognition'] = $recognition;
$_SESSION['recognition'] = $_POST['recognition'];
$_SESSION['valued'] = $valued;
$_SESSION['valued'] = $_POST['valued'];
$_SESSION['supervisor'] = $supervisor;
$_SESSION['supervisor'] = $_POST['supervisor'];
include "oopspage4.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation8'])
{
include "oopspage2.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation9'])
{
$_SESSION['informed'] = $informed;
$_SESSION['informed'] = $_POST['informed'];
$_SESSION['job'] = $job;
$_SESSION['job'] = $_POST['job'];
$_SESSION['treats'] = $treats;
$_SESSION['treats'] = $_POST['treats'];
$_SESSION['satisfy'] = $satisfy;
$_SESSION['satisfy'] = $_POST['satisfy'];
echo "Please save the link inorder to continue your survey http://bonnie/~jnagesh/SampleSurvey/OOPS/oopspage5.php";

}

elseif($_POST['Operation10'])
{
$_SESSION['informed'] = $informed;
$_SESSION['informed'] = $_POST['informed'];
$_SESSION['job'] = $job;
$_SESSION['job'] = $_POST['job'];
$_SESSION['treats'] = $treats;
$_SESSION['treats'] = $_POST['treats'];
$_SESSION['satisfy'] = $satisfy;
$_SESSION['satisfy'] = $_POST['satisfy'];
include "oopspage5.php";
}
elseif($_POST['Operation11'])
{
include "oopspage3.php";
}

elseif($_POST['Operation12'])
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cgiadmin","cgi");
if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("j2", $con);

$person = new person1;
$person->set_location($_POST['location']);
$person->set_effective($_POST['effective']);
$person->set_training($_POST['training']);
$person->set_treated($_POST['treated']);
$person->set_effort($_POST['effort']);
$person->set_information($_POST['information']);
$person->set_recognition($_POST['recognition']);
$person->set_valued($_POST['valued']);
$person->set_supervisor($_POST['supervisor']);
$person->set_informed($_POST['informed']);
$person->set_job($_POST['job']);
$person->set_treats($_POST['treats']);
$person->set_satisfy($_POST['satisfy']);
$person->set_workgroup($_POST['workgroup']);
$person->set_utc($_POST['utc']);
$person->set_skills($_POST['skills']);


$sql="INSERT INTO bigsurvey(location, effective, training , treated , effort, information , recognition,valued,supervisor,informed,job,treats,satisfy,workgroup,utc,skills)
VALUES
('$_SESSION[location]','$_SESSION[effective]','$_SESSION[training]','$_SESSION[treated]','$_SESSION[effort]','$_SESSION[information]','$_SESSION[recognition]','$_SESSION[valued]','$_SESSION[supervisor]','$_SESSION[informed]','$_SESSION[job]','$_SESSION[treats]','$_SESSION[satisfy]','".$person->get_workgroup()."','".$person->get_utc()."','".$person->get_skills()."')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Thanks for taking the survey .";
mysql_close($con);

}
elseif($_POST['Operation13'])
{
include "oopspage4.php";
}
?>
```

My question is , Is this the proper way to do or create a form using Object Oriented concept in php ? Or should I create any more objects or make any changes ?

I tried to include the file classperson.php on all the pages but I get an error when I use the next button .

Thanks in advance

Comment: "var" is oop php4, you should not be using it. if you are using a tutorial that does, its out of date. In php 5 var = public http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: @Dagon Thanks dagon . Will change it right away . Is there any changes that I need to do ?

Comment: It is a standard practice to name a PHP file containing a class with the name of that class. Also, you should be declaring the visibility of your functions.

Comment: Are these five pages all in ooposurvey.php or have you just combined them all together?

Comment: If you are going to use mutator methods, `var` is going to make them useless. You should declare them `private` so that only the mutators can edit them and accessors can access them (Or unless if you don't need hooks added to the mutators or accessors you can completely forgo them because it's unneeded code).

Comment: No , Im sorry . They are all different files . Names OOpspage1.php , oopspage2.php , oopspage3.php, oopspage4.php and oopspage5.php

Comment: @JathinNagesh Good. I figured that you had them separate since there were multiple `<html>` tags, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Thanks PhpMyCoder :) . Should I make any more changes ? is ther a way where I can use Sessions using oops concepts ?

Comment: @JathinNagesh Look into a framework that uses MVC. I wouldn't quite call it "oop" but I find it nicer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what you call "pages" is only used on the client side, but for PHP it is a single script. So there is no sense in, e.g. doing session_start() many times, because every time you send data to the server, the script starts to run from the beginning again. Also it doesn't stop running when it reaches the end of current page.

Secondly, this idea with determining the survey step by session variables is kinda rusty itself, and it's not implemented properly. I'm pretty sure that it doesn't work (though I didn't run the code). There's nothing bad about storing variables in session, but my advice is that you should re-think the logic somehow. For example, you could use some hidden input in every form to check on which step of survey the user is, and in the PHP file have some [switch{}()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) with cases for every page.

Third, not to be so confused, you should separate logic and presentation. What I mean - use separate files for all forms, and separate file which will accepts the data from user, writes it down (as in your example - in session), and chooses what page to show next. That way it will be easier for you to localize errors, and it will settle down in your head more.

And as for your question regarding classes use in PHP: normally you should only include the class once, there is no need to re-include it, e.g. in this file where you will handle all the logic. Then you can create an instance of that class and work with it. Anyhow, I have a feeling that you are in some rush, and it seems to me that it's early for you to start with OOP techniques - it's better to go step by step. Try to make this script work without classes. When it will work extract the logic to a class. That way you gonna understand everything better :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment where you say that the files are separate. Yet, most of my answer remains same :)